# Creating a dataframe within an if statement

Tags: apache-spark

I have noticed some odd behaviour when creating a dataframe within a conditional statements

For instance:

```
val bla = 3
case class Test(foo: Int)

val test = if (bla == 1){
   println("foo")
} else {Seq(4,5,6).toDF}
```

Returns Any

while the following code would return a dataframe

```
val bla = 3
case class Test(foo: Int)

val test = if (bla == 1){
   Seq(1,2,3).toDF
} else {Seq(4,5,6).toDF}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because return type of `println` is `Unit`, so compiler must choose common supertype of `DataFrame` and `Unit` - it's `Any`

You must create DataFrame in `if` and `else`, i.e. empty DataFrame

Variable with DataFrame type must be the last expression in both `if` and `else` block

Comment: LOL you were faster than me :)

Comment: @eliasah Yesterday (or two days ago) I post answer less than minute before others :D

Comment: This was 13 seconds before me :P